# ios convert NSString with special chars to const char

Tags: ios, nsstring, char, nsstringencoding

i m trying to draw a string with CGContextShowTextAtPoint.
CGContextShowTextAtPoint only accepts "const char" as a string input.
my problem is that some of the strings have special chars like ä,ö,ü etc in them.

if i convert this strings to a "const char"

```
NSString *label = @"Küche";
const char *charLabel = [label UTF8String];
```

i get a strange output, where the ü is replaced with signs and boxes...

what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw only ASCII characters with `CGContextShowTextAtPoint`.
To draw Unicode strings use either [NSString UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893) like `drawInRect:withFont:` or (for more customized drawing) [CoreText framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533).